# Replace jQuery version of a page with Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

How can i replace jquery version of a page with greasemonkey?

Im trying to test a site with a newer version of jquery but i dont have a dev enviroment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you're asking about jQuery and Greasemonkey for doing this, but let me off a *completely* different alternative, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

If you're testing a site out with a new version of jQuery and you *actually* want to test any breaking changes, etc...you want to test the site *as it will be*, whereas a JavaScript (greasemonkey)-based after-the-fact replacement isn't an accurate simulation.

With fiddler you can replace the jQuery file *that the browser requests* (without the browser knowing).  This way you're actually testing it completely, you're straight up dropping the new version in the page, no in-page JS tricks which may not be at all accurate to get there (handlers already hooked up, load order, etc.)

[Eric Law](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/) (creator of Fiddler) has an excellent blog post on how to do *exactly* this:

> [Swapping out JQuery with Fiddler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/using-fiddler-to-verify-a-jquery-update-will-fix-a-compatibility-problem.aspx)

The post was written for swapping out the minified version with the full version (also handy!) *or* a newer version for debugging, be sure to note both uses...they're both *very* useful in saving some debug/testing time.

Answer (score 10):

Making a dev environment, using source-control and a written release checklist will save you much grief (and is a requirement for most paid work).
~~~

The best way to replace the jQuery version on an existing page (that you don't control) is to:

1. Stop the page's native jQuery from loading.
2. Create a `<script>` node, containing the jQuery version you want, that loads *before* any subsequent scripts that use jQuery.

Unfortunately, Greasemonkey cannot do #1.  It can only tamper with the page's native jQuery *after* it has loaded -- An approach that might work, but that slows the page and risks race conditions.

So, I recommend **a two-tool solution:**

1. Make sure your Firefox has [the Adblock add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) (which is an excellent add-on to use irregardless) and/or [the RequestPolicy add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/).
2. Use *Adblock* or *RequestPolicy* to temporarily block the old jQuery.
   For example, for StackOverflow, block `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js`. (Note that *RequestPolicy* allows you to limit URL blocking to only a specific site.)
3. Then use Greasemonkey to load the desired version of jQuery (which it can do irregardless of *Adblock* or *RequestPolicy* settings) at the beginning of the page.

   For example, this script will upgrade Meta SO's jQuery to 1.6.2, in conjunction with the block from step 2:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name            _upgrade jQuery
   // @include         http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
   // @run-at          document-start
   // ==/UserScript==

   /*--- Important!
           (1) We need another add-on, besides Greasemonkey, to
               disable the old, undesired script.
           (2) The DOM is not available yet
               (@run-at == document-start).
           (3) We cannot use a loop to check for the DOM because
               loading is halted while the loop runs.
           (4) setTimeout() and setInterval() are not fast enough due
               to minimum interval clamping.  By the time they detect
               the DOM, scripts that we need to precede may have
               loaded.
           (5) Therefor, we use a "set Zero Timeout" function as
               explained by David Baron at
                   http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts .
           (6) By the time FF reports that the `document.head` is
               available, several head elements have loaded!
               (Is this a bug?)
               That means that if any dependent scripts are loaded
               before we can inject our jQuery version, then we must
               also reload those dependent scripts.
   */

   //////  setZeroTimeout() implementation: BEGIN

   /*--- Only add setZeroTimeout to the window object, and hide
       everything else in a closure.
   */
   ( function () {
       var timeouts    = [];
       var messageName = "zero-timeout-message";

       /*--- Like setTimeout, but only takes a function argument.
           There's no time argument (always zero) and no arguments.
           You have to use a closure.
       */
       function setZeroTimeout(fn) {
           timeouts.push(fn);
           window.postMessage(messageName, "*");
       }

       function handleMessage(event) {
           if (event.source == window && event.data == messageName) {
               event.stopPropagation();
               if (timeouts.length > 0) {
                   var fn = timeouts.shift();
                   fn();
               }
           }
       }

       window.addEventListener ("message", handleMessage, true);

       // Add the one thing we want added to the window object.
       window.setZeroTimeout = setZeroTimeout;
   })();

   //////  setZeroTimeout() implementation: END

   /*--- Now wait for the DOM and then add our version of jQuery,
       first thing.
   */
   function SearchForDOM () {

       var targetNode;
       if (typeof document.head == "undefined")
           targetNode = document.querySelector ("head, body");
       else
           targetNode = document.head;
       if (targetNode) {

           var scriptNode      = document.createElement ("script");
           scriptNode.src      = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/'
                               + 'libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js';
           targetNode.appendChild (scriptNode);

           /*--- By the time FF reports that the head element is
               available, a key dependent script has loaded!
               So, we reload it here, so that it can run with jQuery
               available.
           */
           var scriptNode      = document.createElement ("script");
           scriptNode.src      = location.protocol
                               + '\/\/' + location.host
                               + '/content/js/stub.js?v=49f661361016';
           targetNode.appendChild (scriptNode);
       }
       else
           setZeroTimeout (SearchForDOM);
   }

   SearchForDOM ();
   ```

   Note: that due to limitations of JS, GM, and Firefox, it may be necessary to reload scripts that depend on jQuery too.  (This is the case for Meta Stack Overflow, at the moment.)

Comment: Turns out I am trying to do the same thing! I am trying to reload SO in FF56, since google CDN is threshold to 0 speed. I use uMatrix to block it. On document ready, scan script nodes into a queue, reverse and append every script to head starting from jquery. Before that, I tried run@ document-start and event beforescriptexecute to intercept, page loading chokes. Now m trying your way with window.eval(). it works flawlessly. So. just to say thank you for the 0timout trick.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Greasemonkey, but an easy approach to modify any resource on (url, image, script) would be using [Requestly](https://www.requestly.in/) Redirect Rule.

1. Open Requesly app from icon (or navigate to http://app.requestly.in/rules)
2. Click "New Rule"
3. Select "Redirect Request"
4. Enter Request source (in your case, "URL""Equals":[url-to-jquery eg: "http://some-host.com/jquery1.4.js"]
5. Enter Destination (in your case, URL to required jquery version CDN eg: "http://any-host.com/jquery3.2.js")
6. Click Save
7. Done! Now all the requests made by your browser to source url will be redirected to your defined destination url.

Note:

- If you don`t have CDN, you can host the file on web using Requestly Library. Then choose "Select from Library" below Destination URL field.
- The same results can be achieved using Cancel Request rule to block existing request. Then use Insert Scripts rule to insert your version of script into the webpage.

PS: I work at Requestly.

Answer (score 0):

What didn't work for my case, seems to suit this question, no blocker is required. In GreaseMonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        alternative jquery
// @namespace   ben@host
// @description intercept
// @include     https://somehost.com/*
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @resource    jquery_new jquery_new.js
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var jquery_source = GM_getResourceText( 'jquery_new' );
console.log('jQuery Lenght =',jquery_source.length);

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute',  
function(e){
    if (e.target.src &&
        e.target.src.search('/1.12.4/jquery.min.js') >= 0 ) {
            console.log('intercepted: '+e.target.src);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            window.eval(jquery_source);
        }
});
```

Note: downside - `beforescriptexecute` fires after the original script is retrieved and ready to be executed, so should the original external js file failed to load, this approach will not work.